# Power Bi API: Get Power BI datasource data

Tags: c#, .net-core, powerbi

I would like to know whether it's possible to get hold of the data associated with a specific report. This also includes the schema of the data. In other words, if the report makes use of an Excel file, I would like to get hold of the data in that Excel file. Is something like this even possible? I have tried some of the methods, like `GetDatasetAsync` as well as `GetDatasourcesAsAdminWithHttpMessagesAsync`, but it did not provide the desired result.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the options I know of:

1. You can publish a PowerBI dataset and have other reports connect to it. You can find it on the [list of connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/power-bi-data-sources).
2. [Exporting the data from the report (as csv)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data). This only applies to the current visual.
3. You can export visual via PDF or PowerPoint.
4. [XLMA Endpoints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/admin/service-premium-connect-tools) can let you query the model and retrieve what you want programmatically however this is a PREMIUM feature only. [Here is a how-to](https://www.biinsight.com/what-does-xmla-endpoints-mean-for-power-bi-and-how-to-test-it-for-free/).
5. You can build your model in analysis services (SSAS) and have a live connection to the tabular model, then you can work with the data in SSAS using XLMA.

That is about as good as it get's.

Comment: Many thanks Murray for the response! Seems like option 4 is the one that might solve my problem. Let me have a look 